# Why am I getting 403 only on POST requests, even with authorizeHttpRequests set to permitAll?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following...

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationConfig{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz)-> authz.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And I have the following controller...

```java
@RequestMapping("/kafka")
public class KafkaController {
    private final KafkaService service;

    public KafkaController(@Autowired KafkaService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody String message){
        System.out.println("Sending message");
        service.sendMessage(message);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public String acctuator(){
        return "Kafka";
    }
}
```

When I try to access the GET endpoint everything works...

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/kafka
Kafka
```

But when I try to use the post I get...

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/kafka -d "Hello World"
{"timestamp":"2023-08-28","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","path":"/kafka"}
```

How do I allow the POST as well as the GET?

Comment: By default Spring Security protects any incoming POST (or PUT/DELETE/PATCH) request with a valid CSRF token.

Comment: I was about to add the answer but feel free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because spring security by default will enable CSRF protection for all POST requests which require the POST request to provide a valid CSRF token. Otherwise , it will return 403 if the token is missing.

Since the root cause of the CSRF attack is mainly because the server uses cookie to determine if an user is authenticated or not. If you are developing a REST API which normally does not require to use any cookie , you can turn off the CSRF protection as no cookie means no CSRF attack :

```java
 @Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz)-> authz.anyRequest().permitAll());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
 }
```